# How can I resize the Chrome developer mode error console?

Tags: google-chrome, error-console

When opening the error console in Chrome developer mode, the window is too small to display the messages.  I cannot resize the window nor the top portion to view the messages.  Is there a work-around?

It doesn't matter which extension/app I'm working on, it happens every time.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have this same problem. Its not a permanent solution, but this is what I do to see the errors.

[image]